# "select count(1)" performance in a CTE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, performance, cte, performance-tuning, query-performance

Given the below CTE:

```
with seekResults as
(
select DISTINCT
 trx_id_fk,
 account_FK, 
 customer_cif,
 customer_tin,
 TIN_Type, 
 ID_NUMBER ,
 SEARCH_NUMBER
 FROM transactionsOP 
) 

 select trx_id_fk 
  ,case when account_FK is not null then (select count(1) from seekResults a where a.account_fk = s.account_fk and a.SEARCH_NUMBER= s.SEARCH_NUMBER) 
   when customer_cif is not null then (select count(1) from seekResults a where a.customer_cif = s.customer_cif and a.SEARCH_NUMBER= s.SEARCH_NUMBER) 
   when customer_tin is not null then (select count(1) from seekResults a where a.customer_tin = s.customer_tin and a.TIN_Type = s.TIN_Type and a.SEARCH_NUM = s.SEARCH_NUM) 
   when ID_NUMBER is not null then (select count(1) from seekResults a where a.ID_NUMBER = s.ID_NUMBER and a.SEARCH_NUMBER= s.SEARCH_NUMBER)
   else (select count(1) from seekResults a where a.SEARCH_NUMBER= s.SEARCH_NUMBER)
       end as 'transaction_period'
from seekResults s  ;
```

I noticed that it is taking a lot of time doing the calculation because it is calling the `seekResults` CTE over and over again, mostly in the `select count(1) section`:

```
select count(1) from seekResults  a
```

Is there a better way to improve that part ? So far I haven't found anything to replace it with.

Comment: Like in your [last question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194278/sql-server-improve-cte-performance-with-case-statements), the only way to avoid this is to persist the CTE results somewhere. You said you couldn't do that because you were limited to working in a view. Have you chosen a different method for calling the data?

Comment: Hey @sp_BlitzErik, hope you are ok, not possible as there are limitations at backend level.

Comment: Yep @ypercubeᵀᴹ, added...

Comment: Thnx. But there is no `account_FK` in the select list of the CTE. Please correct.

Comment: How is the execution time affected if you add a non-deterministic function like rand() in the cte?

Comment: what version u are using ? We encountered this on the new CE. Try using tf 9481 to see if it helps ?

Answer (score 2):

I think your query can be written using window aggregates. I don't know if it will be more efficient though:

```
with seekResults as
(
  select distinct
    trx_id_fk,
    account_fk
    customer_cif,
    customer_tin,
    tin_type,
    id_number,
    search_number
  from transactionsOP 
) 
select 
  trx_id_fk,  
  case 
    when account_fk is not null then
      count(*) over (partition by search_number, account_fk) 
    when customer_cif is not null then
      count(*) over (partition by search_number, customer_cif) 
    when customer_tin is not null then
      count(*) over (partition by search_number, customer_tin, tin_type)
    when id_number is not null then
      count(*) over (partition by search_number, id_number)
    else 
      count(*) over (partition by search_number)
  end as transaction_period
from seekResults ;
```

Comment: I don't see how you can mix a single row value (trx_id_fk) with a partition by that can return multiple rows

Answer (score 1):

You might try to change it to add one more CTE with windows function, and select from there .

```
with seekResults as
(
select DISTINCT
 trx_id_fk,
 account_FK,
 customer_cif,
 customer_tin,
 ID_NUMBER ,
 SEARCH_NUMBER
 FROM transactionsOP 
) ,
 seekResults2 as 
(
  select  trx_id_fk,
  account_FK,
 customer_cif,
 customer_tin,
 ID_NUMBER ,
 SEARCH_NUMBER,
 count(1) over (partition by account_fk ,SEARCH_NUMBER) as count1,
 count(1) over (partition by customer_cif ,SEARCH_NUMBER) as count2,
 count(1) over (partition by customer_tin , TIN_Type, SEARCH_NUMBER) as count3, 
  count(1) over (partition by ID_NUMBER , SEARCH_NUMBER) as count4
 from seekResults
)
 SELECT  trx_id_fk 
  ,case when account_FK is not null then count1 .... 
 FROM seekResults2
```

Comment: Not seeing how this works.  The partition by will return multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to made some sense of this.

Odd a trx_id_fk can have more than one SEARCH_NUMBR but SEARCH_NUMBER is not reported.  For that matter trx_id_fk cazn have multiple account_FK and account_FK is not reported.

OP it is not clear what you are trying to do.  I am not sure this is what you mean to to.

```
with seekResults as
( select DISTINCT
         trx_id_fk,
         account_FK, 
         customer_cif,
         customer_tin,
         TIN_Type, 
         ID_NUMBER ,
         SEARCH_NUMBER
  FROM transactionsOP 
) 

select trx_id_fk 
     , case when account_FK   is not null then (select count(1) from seekResults a   
                                                where a.account_fk    = s.account_fk 
                                                  and a.SEARCH_NUMBER = s.SEARCH_NUMBER) 
            when customer_cif is not null then (select count(1) from seekResults a  
                                                where a.customer_cif  = s.customer_cif 
                                                  and a.SEARCH_NUMBER = s.SEARCH_NUMBER) 
            when customer_tin is not null then (select count(1) from seekResults a   
                                                where a.customer_tin  = s.customer_tin and a.TIN_Type = s.TIN_Type 
                                                  and a.SEARCH_NUM    = s.SEARCH_NUM) 
            when ID_NUMBER    is not null then (select count(1) from seekResults a 
                                                where a.ID_NUMBER     = s.ID_NUMBER 
                                                  and a.SEARCH_NUMBER = s.SEARCH_NUMBER)
            else                               (select count(1) from seekResults a 
                                                where a.SEARCH_NUMBER = s.SEARCH_NUMBER)
        end as 'transaction_period'
from seekResults s;
```